# covert large array of objects into smaller array objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an list of values like this from a sql database.

```
UserName  Email                  ComputerName      DateIssued
jjsmith   jjsmith@example.com    JTComputer        9/14/2013
ltjoseph  ltjoseph@example.com   LTComputer1       10/21/2013
KTsmith   KevinTem@example.com   KTComputer1       01/25/2012
ltjoseph  ltjoseph@example.com   LTComputer2       01/11/2013
KTsmith   KevinTem@example.com   KTComputer2       01/25/2012
```

I transform my list into an array of objects.

```
   var user_array = [
{"username":"jjsmith",  "email":"jjsmith@example.com",   "computerName":"JTComputer",  "dateissued":"10/21/2013"}
{"username":"ltjoseph", "email":"ltjoseph@example.com",  "computerName":"LTComputer1", "dateissued":"10/21/2013"}
{"username":"KTsmith",  "email":"KevinTem@example.com",  "computerName":"KTComputer1", "dateissued":"01/25/2012"}
{"username":"ltjoseph", "email":"ltjoseph@example.com",  "computerName":"LTComputer2", "dateissued":"01/11/2013"}
{"username":"KTsmith",  "email":"KevinTem@example.com",  "computerName":"KTComputer2", "dateissued":"01/25/2012"}]
```

A function has been created by someone else that sends emails to users, it only accepts two parameters which are strings.
    So I don't want to send more than 1 email per user. So I am trying to figure out how to combine the items together so that my an example set of strings look like this.

```
var str1 = "ltjoseph@example.com";
var str2 = "ltjoseph, LTComputer1-10/21/2013, LTComputer2-01/11/2013";
```

and then fire the other user function to send emails for each of the items in the list.

```
 function sendEmails(str1, str2);
```

If anyone has any ideas how i can do this. Please advise..

Comment: post the full sendEmails method...

Comment: So you're pretty much need to "GROUP BY" email/name and aggregate all computer names? @shennan method is irrelevant here

Comment: @shennan i do not have access to that method, all I know is what it takes in.

Comment: `var userArray = [ /* user data */];` is better. variable name is descriptive and you're currently lacking a `=` when declaring your var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var by_user = {};
for (var i = 0; i < user_array.length; i++) {
    if (by_user[user_array[i].username]) {
        // Found user, add another computer
        by_user[user_array[i].username].str2 += ', ' + user_array[i].computerName + '-' + user_array[i].dateissued;
    } else {
        // First entry for user, create initial object
        by_user[user_array[i].username] = {
            str1: user_array[i].email,
            str2: user_array[i].username + ', ' + user_array[i].computerName + '-' + user_array[i].dateissued
        };
    }
}
```

Now you have the `by_user` object, which has a single sub-object for each user, whose `str1` and `str2` properties are the variables you want.

```
by_user['ltjoseph'].str1 => ltjoseph@example.com
by_user['ltjoseph'].str2 => ltjoseph, LTComputer1-10/21/2013, LTComputer2-01/11/2013
```

Comment: I tried implementing the code above all that happens is the each item is just listed in str1 and st2, how does it actually determine if the user exists? Because by_user[array[i].username] doesn't ever come back true.

Comment: @Barmar...I thought to access an object all i needed to do was by_user[user_array[i]].str1 or by_user[user_array[i]].str2, but it comes back undefined.

Comment: I get more than one line for ltjoseph and KTsmith.  For example it shows ltjoseph, LTComputer1-10/21/2013, then later on it shows ltjoseph@example.com   ltjoseph, LTComputer1-10/21/2013, LTComputer2-01/11/2013

Comment: I fixed another typo (`dateIssued` should be `dateissued` -- I was looking at your table headings instead of the object), but that should have no effect on that. I don't know how you can have multiple lines for a name, since property names are unique in an object. I tested me code, and added sample output in the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. You're looping through `user_array`. Of course that still has duplicates, I didn't do anything to it. If you want to just process unique entries, iterate through `by_user`, not `user_array`.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
var str1=array[0].email
var str2=array[0].username+", "+array[0].computerName+array[0].dateissued
```

or use a loop and iterate through the array

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend bringing in a library like lodash for this sort of thing and using [uniq](http://lodash.com/docs#uniq) (sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/MwYtU/):

```
var uniqs = lodash(user_array).pluck('email').uniq().value();
```

If you're doing javascript and aren't acquainted with `lodash` or `underscore`, go do that because it'll save you a lot of time. Using tried and true code is a good idea. Added bonus: if you want to see how the pros are doing something like `uniq` you can just look at the source code.